# Texture paint has suddenly stopped appearing

Tags: texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

Fellas, I'm at the end of my rope here. I've tried looking up most every other solution to this issue I could find and none of them have worked. I was texture painting as usual and at some point it just stopped being visible. However, the little asterisk by the Image showed up every time I made a scribble, so it must be doing *something.* If anything here looks like it could be wrong, please let me know.
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe pack your image and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: do you have set a mask for the brush? is the correct UV map active?

Comment: There is no mask set for the brush, and I've got the right UV map. I've got the blend here, I'm hoping I've got it all copied and packed correctly. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=1eNJ07d3" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/1eNJ07d3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see there's a texture that has been selected for your brush, plus it's completely black so when you paint you don't see anything. Just close it:

[image]